# How can I query for the definitions of all domains in the database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-metadata

I'm trying to find a way to run a SELECT query (not some admin command) that returns the definition for every domain type in a Postgres database.  Specifically, I'd like to know:

- Schema
- Name
- Underlying type
- Null/not null

Trying to Google this is tricky, because searching for information about querying the definitions of custom types in Postgres gives tons of results about *enums* for some reason, but nothing useful about domains.  Does anyone know how to retrieve domain definitions from Postgres metadata?

Comment: See here [Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/catalog-pg-type.html) in particular column `typtype`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It looks like `typtype` will tell me that "this is a domain," which is useful, but it won't tell me "this is a domain representing a `varchar(20) not null`," which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns what you ask for, plus some more columns that may be relevant:

```sql
SELECT n.nspname AS schema
     , t.typname AS name
     , pg_catalog.format_type(t.typbasetype, t.typtypmod) AS underlying_type
     , t.typnotnull AS not_null
       
     , (SELECT c.collname
        FROM   pg_catalog.pg_collation c, pg_catalog.pg_type bt
        WHERE  c.oid = t.typcollation AND bt.oid = t.typbasetype AND t.typcollation <> bt.typcollation) AS collation
     , t.typdefault AS default
     , pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, TRUE) FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint r WHERE t.oid = r.contypid), ' ') AS check_constraints
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_type t
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
WHERE  t.typtype = 'd'  -- domains
AND    n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
AND    pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=53c66cbcd13176c04fc1c008f1c9f708)*

To get ***every domain type in a Postgres database*** remove the added filters:

```
AND    n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
AND    pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)
```

But you'll probably just want visible user-domains.

Read the manual about [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html).

In psql use `\dD`. And if you do that after setting `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on`, you'll also see the query used to generate that output. You'll find similarities to my query above (hint!).